# What to do when container in `Docker-compose up` has no output?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is less about any particular solution and more about how to dig into it to see what's happening. I have a `docker-compose.yml` file as follows:

```
version: '2.2'
services:
  kibana:
    image: docker.elastic.co/kibana/kibana:6.6.0
    container_name: kibana
```

I have no containers, `docker container list -a` is empty. No networks or volumes either.

When I run `docker-compose up` I never get any output:

```
Creating network "kibana_default" with the default driver
Creating kibana ... done
Attaching to kibana
```

If I add in an elastic search configuration to the same yml file I get output from that but the kibana container remains silent. So it appears it's specific to kibana in this context.

I'm aware that restarting docker or the computer will likely resolve the issue but I'd like to understand what's happening.

So my question is, if a container isn't spitting output what's my next step? Is there some other way I can make it tell me what's happening?

**EDIT:** I should note in case there is any question, I don't believe this has anything to do with the Kibana image itself. It's far more likely I have a configuration setting causing this behavior that I'm unaware of. The purpose of this question was to help me figure out what that setting might be.

Comment: next step is checking logs https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/

Comment: This is my first time using the logs command so I may be using it incorrectly. `docker logs kibana --since 2019-02-20` (I just picked yesterday to try to get everything) shows nothing.

Comment: Some images just don’t write anything to their stdout.  I haven’t specifically looked at the Kibana image in quite a while, but it’s possible you’ll need to mount a host directory to the container’s log directory to actually see its log output.

Comment: @DavidMaze - Kibana does usually. I'm not sure why it wasn't in this case but the problem resolved itself on reboot. /shrugs

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have *an* (probably not *the*) answer. I'm still unsure what the problem is but this seems like another thread I can pull on if necessary.

I can create a docker build script starting with the kibana image:

```
FROM docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.6.0
```

From here I have a lot of options. I could add some command to the image that would spit out some kind of output and then launch kibana. This would help me understand if it's a problem with output just not making it to where I can see it. That narrows things down considerably. If kibana is just hanging inexplicably this build script lets me tweak some settings and the default entry point flags to try to get something different to happen.

This may be obvious to others and there may be better ways of accomplishing this. I'm just documenting my journey here.

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to stdout buffering. That is in your case there may not be enough output text from the container to trigger output. Default logger driver [json-file](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/) does always use buffering.

You may running it with a different logger driver as
`docker run --log-driver journald ...` (see also [logging drive configuration](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/) for system-wide settings, and [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) for per-container logging options)

If the buffering happens on the container side, try adding explicit stdout flushes to see the output sooner. For example, in Python it would be

```py
print("A message.")
sys.stdout.flush()
```

This may not be an option with an existing image as the one you are using, though.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not helpful, but in my case there is a very weird behaviour:

`docker compose up` doesn't show output, it just hangs on "attaching" forever

But, if I open a `screen` session, and run the `docker compose up` command from it, then I get output.

If I cancel the docker running, close the screen session, I can run `docker compose up` outside the screen instance and then output is display.